# Country -> State-> City with angular-schema-form-dynamic-select

Tags: angularjs, jsonschema, angular-schema-form

I am currently using angular-schema-form-dynamic-select and my requirement is to select states based on a country selected. I'm storing data in the db like this **country -> state -> city**. Can anyone Help me on this?

This is my form:

```json
[
  {
    "key": "country",
    "type": "strapselect",
    "placeholder":"country",
    "options": {
      "httpGet": {
        "url": "/countries" 
      },
      "map": { "valueProperty": "readonlyProperties.id", "nameProperty":"name" }
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "state",
    "type": "strapselect",
    "placeholder":"state",
    "options": {            
      "httpGet": {
        "url": "/states"         
      },
      "map": { "valueProperty": "readonlyProperties.id", "nameProperty":"name" }
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "city",
    "type": "strapselect",
    "placeholder":"city",
    "options": {
      "httpGet": {
        "url": "/cities"
      },
      "map": { "valueProperty": "readonlyProperties.id", "nameProperty":"name" }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: can u show some related code

Answer (score 0):

**I think a feature like that would be indeed quite handy. Maybe you write something like this in the json string:**

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "country": {
            "type": "string",
            "enumCallback": "getTitlesValues()"
        }
    }
}
```

**And in your controller you would have that callback defined:**

```
...
$scope.getTitlesValues = function () {
    return ['India','Australia', 'Germany', 'Sweden']
}
...
```

Answer (score -1):

**I think a feature like that would be indeed quite handy.
Maybe you write something like this in the json string:**

```
        {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
        "country": {
        "type": "string",
        "enumCallback": "getTitlesValues()"
           }
         }
       }
```

**And in your controller you would have that callback defined:**

```
             ...
            $scope.getTitlesValues = function () {
            return ['India','Australia', 'Germany', 'Sweden']
           }
            ...
```